# Are Z3 caches additive?

Tags: caching, z3, z3py

I'm aware that Z3 has stack-based caching, where additional formulas can be added and cached. Is there a built-in way or extension that allows two Z3 caches to be combined?

**Example (Z3 py)**

```
from z3 import Solver

solver = Solver()
solver.push()
solver2 = Solver()
# solver.combine(solver2) ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite cleear what you mean by "combine." But, you can get the assertions from one and add it to the other:

```py
from z3 import *

i = Int('x')
s1 = Solver()
s1.add(i == 3)
s1.push()

s2 = Solver()
s2.add(s1.assertions())
print s2.check()
print s2.model()
```

This prints:

```
sat
[x = 3]
```

You can use this trick to do your own combinations I suppose.

Comment: Hi There, by combine I mean to reuse the derivations as part of both solvers. Combining the assertions does not offer any performance benefits in this case.

Comment: I don't think you can share "learnings" in any meaningful way. Note that z3py 'Solver' is a thin-wrapper over the underlying solver-context, and so far as I know there's no way to combine those in any way. You might want to ask at their issues site to see if this is a possibility. (Though keep in mind that even if it's possible in the underlying layer, it doesn't mean it'd be exposed to the user via the Python API.)